# What does "data trail for transactions" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Today when reading a working paper of [Auer 2021](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/ba9ae483-5708-3339-8def-850796239da3/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7Be7429c1f-2909-3945-bedb-046c720d14f8%7D) about CBDC (Central Bank Digital Currency), I found a sentence:

> Conversely, central banks in jurisdictions with a large informal
> (“shadow”) economy may have greater interest in creating a **data trail
> for transactions**, and thus promoting use of a digital currency.

I understand that "[informal economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informal_economy)" is a part of a country that neither be taxed or monitored by any form of governments.

***However, I do not understand what "data trail for transactions" means, leading to the ambiguity about the meaning of this sentence.***

Answer (score 2):

[data trail](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/data_trail)

> The potentially recoverable traces of data left behind by any activity

They want a way to track what transactions happened.  This, for instance, would let them prove what happened if it turns out they are peripherally involved in criminal activity, and they want to show their innocence.

Comment: Probably from 'paper trail' in earlier times;